Как убрать определённые логи? loggin Python Aiogram Telegram bot
Пишу простого бота для телеграмма. При запуске логи засоряются сообщениями "INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=123123123 is not handled. Duration 14 ms by bot id=123123123". Изменение уровня логирования мне не подходит. Нужно убрать именно логи, связанные с aiogram.event. Пытался использовать это:
aiogram_logger = logging.getLogger('aiogram')
aiogram_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Но ничего не происходило.

Если, по какой-то причине необходимо отключить именно информационные aiogram.event, то вот так:
logging.getLogger("aiogram.event").setLevel(logging.WARNING) 

